# Working with many to one in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have created a many to one relationship N:1 like this

```
class Score {
    Double value
    Criteria criteria
    static belongTo = [criterias: Criteria]
}

class Criteria {
    String name
}
```

so my issue is that I want to use `g:select` to store scores of certain criteria name to database.
i have this form

```
   <g:form controller="audition" action="assignScore">

    <label for="vocal" class="control-label">vocal</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <g:select  from="${['0','10','20','30','40','50','60','70','80','90','100']}" name="vocal" value="score"   noSelection="['':'-choose Score please-']"/>
        <span class="help-inline">${hasErrors(bean: contestantInstance, field: 'vocal', 'error')}</span>

</div>

    <label for="stage" class="control-label">stage</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <g:select  from="${['0','10','20','30','40','50','60','70','80','90','100']}" name="stage" value="score"   noSelection="['':'-choose Score please-']"/>
        <span class="help-inline">${hasErrors(bean: contestantInstance, field: 'stage', 'error')}</span>

</div>
       <div class="form-actions">
           <g:submitButton name="save" class="btn btn-primary" value="save" />
           <button class="btn" type="reset">Cancel</button>
       </div>

   </g:form>
```

and the action in the controller

```
 def assignScore = {
    //find a criteria  name
  def criteriaInstance =  Criteria.findByNameLike(params.vocal)  ?: new Criteria(name: "vocal").save(flush: true)
    if (params.vocal == "vocal"){
    def score = new Score()

        score.properties=params.vocal


        criteriaInstance.addToScores(score)
        criteriaInstance.save(flush: true)
    }

    def criteriaInstanceStage =  Criteria.findByNameLike(params.stage)  ?: new Criteria(name: "stage").save(flush: true)

    if (params.stage == "stage"){
        def score = new Score()
        score.properties=params.stage

        criteriaInstanceStage.addToScores(score)
        criteriaInstanceStage.save(flush: true)
    }


}
```

problem is I cant save scores associated with certain criteria

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: i just want to store score values in association of certain criteria see the g:select             <g:select  from="${['0','10','20','30','40','50','60','70','80','90','100']}" name="stage" value="score"   noSelection="['':'-choose Score please-']"/>
i have add my action in the QN

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Tags/select.html) you can use the g:select without any problems.

```
<g:select name="criteria"
          from="${Criteria.list()}"
          value="${criteria}"
 />
```

Please be aware that Criteria may be a reserved word.

Comment: thanks for hints,but i want the g :select to capture certain criteria like this               <g:select  from="${['0','10','20','30','40','50','60','70','80','90','100']}" name="stage" value="score"   noSelection="['':'-choose Score please-']"/>
how this choosen score can be associated with the criteria eg vocal or stage performance.